# Does anyone know of a show where a kid could turn into digital monsters and his dad worked an ice cream store

Tags: story-identification, tv

He went through portals to a digital world (not Digimon) and could turn into digital beings. I remember a sort of panda and the terracotta army. There was an evil corporation.

Comment: Cartoon, I'm guessing? Do you know which network?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint_the_Time_Detective feels like a partial match, although it's time travel, not a digital world.

Comment: When did you watch this?

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail. Do you recall where and when you watched this?

Comment: @vfgasebhn - An anonymous user has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from others, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.